# width doesn't fit to text with multiline inline-block element

Tags: html, css

If you take a look at the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xs5trzxx/

```
<div class="box">
    <h1>This heading</h1>
    <h1>This is one heading</h1>
</div>

.box {
    width: 350px;
}

h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('http://networkmotion.rnmcloud.com/wp-content/themes/networkmotion/images/blue_arrows.png') no-repeat right top;
    padding-right: 100px;
}
```

As you can see the width of the first heading is the width of the text and the background image sits nicely after the text. In the second heading though the width of the heading doesn't fit to the width of the text so the background image is floating off to the right.

How can I make the width of the headings always shrink to be as small as possible so that the background image is always close to the text?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove width

```css
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('http://networkmotion.rnmcloud.com/wp-content/themes/networkmotion/images/blue_arrows.png') no-repeat right top;
    padding-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <h1>This is one heading</h1>
    <h1>This heading</h1>
</div>
```

If you want to show all h1 in new line then add all h1 in different div tag

Answer (score 0):

You could set the headings to `display: inline;`. But you'll also have to clear them if you have more than one (to prevent them sitting side by side, which is easy enough but off topic).

```css
.box {
    width: 350px;
}


h1 {
    display: inline;
    background: url('http://networkmotion.rnmcloud.com/wp-content/themes/networkmotion/images/blue_arrows.png') no-repeat right top;
    padding-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <h1>This is one heading</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove width of ".box" will make it work. But the heading will always 1 line. If you allow multi-line heading, maybe you can try below:

```css
.headTxt {
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    margin:0px;  
}

.headImg {
    float: left
}
```

```html
<div>
        <h1 class="headTxt">This is one heading</h1>
        <div class="headImg"><img src='http://networkmotion.rnmcloud.com/wp-content/themes/networkmotion/images/blue_arrows.png' /></div>
</div>
```